# Dialogflow ES non-default region is not showing system entities tab

Tags: dialogflow-es

If I create an agent in an region except "default", I am not able to see the system entities tab.

The system entities correct identify and add themselves when building training phrases, but I cannot extend even the extensible ones because there is no tab.

If I try and add a custom entity, even though that tab is completely empty, I get a warning:

```
"com.google.apps.framework.request.FailedPreconditionException: This entity's displayName 'sys.geo-city' already exists with current agent. Code: FAILED_PRECONDITION"
```

I know that for a CX agent, [I cannot use some system entities outside US region](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-entities) but that [does NOT apply to ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities).

Can anyone advise?

---

[image: Regional entities tab]

---

[image: Global entities tab]

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/region#limits) it is stated that "Some system entities are currently available only in the following regions: us-central1, us-east1, us-west1, global. Consider creating custom entities or using @sys.any with form parameters", so if the system entities tab is not shown in the region you chose, it's due to this region not being between the ones that have system entites available.

If you find that some entities are missing in a region that you would like to use, you can notify it using [this public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194532569) or opening a new one specifying your preferences.

Comment: Thank you. However, I had already found that documentation and it applies to CX only, not ES, which is the edition I'm using. That issue tracker also applies to CX, and not ES.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'll leave the answer here because if someone finds it I think it provides value, since it points to a public issue which could be of interest. About your question, I have indeed checked that entities are not shown for Dialogflow ES but there's nothing in the documentation that points this out. You can create a feature request in a public issue to forward this and let the product team know about this apparent inconsistency between the documentation and the product.

Comment: Thank you - so do you think this is actually just poor documentation, rather than a bug in the interface? Because the fact is, the system entities DO exist in that locale, because the system detects and displays them in the training phrases, but it is just that they are not displayed in the tab and therefore not extendable.

Comment: I think that this is an inconsistency between documentation and product. You can ask on a public issue so that you get an answer on what it is really, if it is either poor documentation or a feature that should be fixed.